# Where is $TERM set in Linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables, settings

Specifically Ubuntu 16.04 but is there a general way it is set?  The reason I ask is that I have several Ubuntu 16.04 installations (VMs on kvm/libvirt/qemu) where nothing specific was done to set this variable at installation and yet they have different values: linux, xterm, xterm-256color and there was one other I can't remember.

I have searched /etc and even opened up initrd in an effort to find where it is set to no avail.

I know it can be set in the user's environment (.profile or .bashrc) but I would prefer to set it globally rather than in numerous places.  These systems have existing users so updating /etc/skel/bashrc is only a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the responsibility of the ssh client to set this variable, so look in ssh_config on the client device first. Then the various user files in your home directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I see I should have mentioned that the same client was connecting to all these systems.  Anyway, I did check the client and there's nothing setting TERM in ssh_config (or sshd_config for that matter).